# installing scipy can't find fortran mac

Tags: python, macos, scipy

I'm having huge troubles installing scipy.

When i run:
    pip install scipy

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

However when i do import scipy in python I get the no module called scipy error.

When i try via easy_install scipy, it starts downloading and then gives me:

```
error: Setup script exited with error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

When i try to install gfortran via brew I get: brew gfortran

```
Error: No available formula for gfortran 
GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with:
brew install gcc
```

But when i try to do that I get:

```
(py)Shopkicks-MacBook-Air-12:shopkick markthornburg$ brew install gcc
Warning: gcc-5.2.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried manually linking gfortran to `/usr/local/bin`, e.g.:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/bin/gfortran /usr/local/bin/
```

You might need to substitute the path to gfortran depending on the version installed.

You might also want to set:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/include/c++/4.8.2:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Again, these path might need changing on your system (depending on the version)